# How can I make a dynamically allocated array of structures?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

For this problem I am being given a list of movies, their genre, etc. I have to then read that file and put it into an array of structures. I am trying to dynamically allocate the array but I don't know how to do that correctly.

I have it as

```
list1 = (list_t *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Not sure what is wrong with this but I am certain it is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`movies = (list_t *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));` Allocates one integer for each record, not a record. This means you don't have as much space as you need and so you are reading data into memory you don't own. That is undefined behavior. You need `movies = malloc(n * sizeof(list_t));`

You also use the `FILE* pointer` after closing the file. That won't work...

Extra advice: Why use `m` in the second loop? Just use `i` directly. Don't use the name `pointer` for the `FILE*`. `fp` is commonly used `inputfile` is arguably better.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. You're right using i would make more sense, not sure why I used m. I'm fairly new to coding and have to do this for a class so not too sure about what is necessarily good and bad for names so I appreciate the help with that. My next question would then be is how come I can't use pointer again after if pointer opens the file??

Comment: You `fclose()` the file, so now it isn't open any more. You could `fopen` it again or get rid of the `fclose` and use `fseek` to rewind the file.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `sizeof(int)` gives you just that, the size in bytes of an integer. So, in the statement:

```
movies = (list_t *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

You're actually allocating memory space for `n` integers, which would be ok if your `list_t` has size the same of an integer, but it's not the case. You need to allocate space for `n` `list_t`s like this:

```
movies = malloc(n * sizeof(list_t));
```

Also, you close the file pointer with `fclose(pointer)` but then you use it in the next `for` loop: `fscanf(pointer, ...)`, that's a mistake. You could do `fopen` to it again or drop the `fclose` and use `fseek` to go back to the start of the file. As a final note, you don't need to use `m` in this loop, you can use `i` like this:

```
..., movies[i].title, movies[i].genre, &movies[i].avscore, movies[i].rating, &movies[i].rentals, &movies[i].year);
```

and then remove `m++` statement along with the `m` variable altogether.